# Bluetooth not working: Intel Wireless AC and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, hp

Bluetooth toggle does nothing:

[image: bluetooth toggle]

sudo bluetoothctl:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect f
No default controller available
```

rfkill:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

sudo systemctl status bluetooth:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-09-20 19:24:38 IST; 35min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 976 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9351)
     Memory: 2.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─976 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 20 19:24:32 HP-Pavilion systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 20 19:24:32 HP-Pavilion bluetoothd[976]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Sep 20 19:24:38 HP-Pavilion systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 20 19:24:39 HP-Pavilion bluetoothd[976]: Starting SDP server
Sep 20 19:24:39 HP-Pavilion bluetoothd[976]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: It might help if you clarify your release, Ubuntu 20? no such release, so is this *snap* based Ubuntu Core 20?  (*yy* format is used for all *snap* based Ubuntu releases, *yy.mm* for standard deb based releases)